# regex: replacing the 1st occurrence of a character in a string

Tags: regex

I have this string:-

ABCDE/Something something:XYZ=0, JKLM=0/SOMETHING Something:some_value

What is the regex so that only the first colon (:) is replaced with underscore (_)?

Comment: Are you using Perl, .NET, python or what?

Comment: Most regex flavors replace only the first match unless you set the global flag in the regex.

Comment: @Amarghosh: you also have to consider the method that's used to *apply* the regex. For example, `replaceAll()` vs `replaceFirst()` in Java.

Comment: @Alan I guess Java doesn't have `g` flag; right?

Comment: @Amarghosh: Right; it's all done through the Matcher class's API.  In one respect `/g` isn't needed; Matcher always keeps track of the next match position, so repeated `find()` calls work as expected.  And repeated `find()` calls is what you have to do; there's no method for finding all matches at once, like .NET's `Matches()`, PHP's `preg_match_all()`, etc.  AFAIK, it's the only major flavor that doesn't have such a method, and it gets damned annoying at times.

Comment: thanks guys for all your comments. really appreciate it. i am using Perl btw. plus, i managed to come up with my own solution to that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In standard systems, you simply write:

```
s/:/_/
```

To achieve a global replace (replacing every instance of colon with underscore) you'd add a qualifier (often 'g') after the substitution.

Different languages use different notations for regular expressions, so the detailed answer depends on the target language.  However, what I wrote works in 'sed', 'ed', 'vi', 'vim', and Perl.

Answer (score 1):

Just match two groups - the first being everything before the first colon; the second, everything after it. Then just rebuild the string with the underscore in place.

```
s/([^:]*):(.*)/\1_\2/
```

You will need differing escaping depending on the language/regex-engine you use.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in regex using a negative lookbehind, but that's relatively inefficient:

```
(?<!:.*):
```

Will only match a colon if no other colon has been previously matched.

However, since you're only replacing one character, not a pattern of characters, I would suggest using the language's native "replace" function. You'll get better performance and readability.

Comment: That might work in the .NET or JGSoft flavors, but most flavors require the lookbehind expression to match substrings with a known, fixed length.  Anyway, lookbehinds should never be your first resort; there's almost always a better way.

Answer (score 0):

if you are on *nix and have tools like `sed`

```
$ echo "ABCDE/Something something:XYZ=0, JKLM=0/SOMETHING Something:some_value" | sed 's/:/_/'
ABCDE/Something something_XYZ=0, JKLM=0/SOMETHING Something:some_value
```

also, if you are using bash as your shell

```
$ var="ABCDE/Something something:XYZ=0, JKLM=0/SOMETHING Something:some_value"
$ echo ${var/:/_}
ABCDE/Something something_XYZ=0, JKLM=0/SOMETHING Something:some_value
```