# Replacing first occurrence of a wildcard string in text file

Tags: regex, perl, replace

I am trying to replace first occurrence of `ZOWG628UT7PQCWQ_PDB1` with `TENANT1_PDB1` in below pattern which is there in a file.

`ZOWG628UT7PQCWQ_PDB1 = (description= (address=(host=slc12ebg)) (connect_data=(service_name=ZOWG628UT7PQCWQ_PDB1_low.xyz.com)) (security=(ssl_server_cert_dn="CN=adwc-dev.uscom-east-1.xyz.com,OU=Testing Domain,O=End Point)) )`

Please note that `ZOWG628UT7PQCWQ` is a variable in string and will keep changing and ZOWG628UT7PQCWQ_PDB1 has to be replaced with TENANT1_PDB1.

I tried `perl -pi -e 's/.*_PDB1/TENANT1_PDB1/' filename.txt` but this is replacing till second occurrence of `ZOWG628UT7PQCWQ_PDB` and giving output as follows which is not required:

`TENANT1_PDB1_low.xyz.com)) (security=(ssl_server_cert_dn="CN=adwc-dev.uscom-east-1.xyz.com,OU=Testing Domain,O=End Point)) )`

I need output like:

`TENANT1_PDB1 = (description= (address=(host=slc12ebg)) (connect_data=(service_name=ZOWG628UT7PQCWQ_PDB1_low.xyz.com)) (security=(ssl_server_cert_dn="CN=adwc-dev.uscom-east-1.xyz.com,OU=Testing Domain,O=End Point)) )`

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [regex: replacing the 1st occurrence of a character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286925/regex-replacing-the-1st-occurrence-of-a-character-in-a-string)

Comment: I tried with following perl inline command:

 perl -pi -e 's/.*_PDB1/TENANT1_PDB1/' filename.txt


This problem doesn't seems related to below as in my problem random string (i.e ZOWG628UT7PQCWQ) also has to be replaced.


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286925/regex-replacing-the-1st-occurrence-of-a-character-in-a-string

Answer (score 1):

Regex quantifiers like `*` and `+` are greedy, meaning if they can match more, they will. To make them "non-greedy", add a `?` after the quantifier.

In your case, changing the pattern to `.*?_PDB1` should only change the first occurrence (if there is one) in each line.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex has some problem, when you say `.*_PDB1`, it goes for greedy match and replaces everything till last match.
You can go for: `perl -p -i.bak -e 's/.*_PDB1 /TENANT1_PDB1/' filename.txt`. Please notice, I have added one space after `_PDB1`.
 Or you can also go for lazy matching `perl -p -i.bak -e 's/.*?_PDB1/TENANT1_PDB1/' filename.txt`

Answer (score 0):

must be more restrict the match search by some regex anchor or class set

```
perl -pi -e 's/^\w+(_PDB1)/TENANT1$1/'
```

or `s/\b\w+(_PDB1)/TENANT1$1/` or whatever you think better see https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html